# Radio button Values not Parsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui, radio-button

I am building a point calculation system that calculates points based on input value.
I've used some jquery ui styling on this radio button and now it doesnt add up, in the total.
Code is too long to post here so check this [live preview](http://onthemouse.com/files/immi/quebec.htm). i read through code a lot of times cou;ldnt find anything.

EDIT: here's a stripped down version of my code:
the problem is with the radio buttons in div part2, please read my comments.

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Quebec and Federal Immigration Points Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="files/jquery00.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="files/flexselect.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="files/demos000.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="files/liquidmetal.js"></script>
    <script src="files/jquery.flexselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $("select.flexselect").flexselect();
            $( ".radio" ).buttonset();//here they are made into jquery ui buttonsets
            $('#part1').show('slow', function() {
            });
            });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function showAge(){ 
    var d =document.getElementById('dob').value.split('/'); 
    var today = new Date(); 
    var bday = new Date(d[2],d[1],d[0]);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - bday.getFullYear();  
    if(today.getMonth() < bday.getMonth() || (today.getMonth() == bday.getMonth() && today.getDate() < bday.getDate()))  
    {
         t = age-1;  
    }
    else {
    t = age
    }
    document.getElementById('form').age.value = t;
    } 
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function compute(form)
    {
    var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('form').age.value, 10) || 0; 
    if ((18 <= a) && (a <= 35)){
        q = 16;
    }
    else if (a == 36){
        q = 14;
    }
    else if (a == 37){
        q = 12;
    }
    else if (a == 38){
        q = 10;
    }
    else if (a == 39){
        q = 8;
    }
    else if (a == 40){
        q = 6;
    }
    else if (a == 41){
        q = 4;
    }
    else if (a == 42){
        q = 2;
    }
    else if ((18 > a) || (a > 43)){
        q = 0;
    }
    var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('form').highed.value, 10) || 0;
    if (b == 1){
        c = 0;
    }
    else if (b == 2){
        c = 2;
    }
    else if (b == 3){
        c = 4;
    }
    else if (b == 4){
        c = 6;
    }
    var aos = parseInt(document.getElementById('form').selectareaofstudy.value, 10) || 0;
//here the value of the radiio button is parsed, and if nothing is selected it will default to zero
    var tcfc2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('form').TCFC2.value, 10) || 0;
    qt = (aos + c + q + tcfc2); 
    document.getElementById('total').age.value = q;
    document.getElementById('total').ed.value = c;
    document.getElementById('total').aos.value = aos;
    document.getElementById('total').tcfc2.value = tcfc2;//here the value is displayed
    document.getElementById('total').total.value = qt;//total displayed here   
    }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function show2() {
        $('#part1').hide('fast');
          $('#part2').show('slow');
    }
    function back2() {
        $('#part1').show('slow');
          $('#part2').hide('fast');
    }
    function showTCF() {
    if($('#radio1-1').is(':checked')) { alert("it's checked"); }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="formbox">
      <form id="form" name="form">
        <div id="part1" style="display:none">
          <div id="hidden">
            <p>Your Date of Birth (format:<strong>dd/mm/yyyy</strong>)</p>
            <br />
            <input onBlur="compute(this.form)" onchange="showAge()" name="dob" id="dob" />
          </div>
          <p>Your Age</p>
          <input class="sev" name="age" type="text" onMouseOver="compute(this.form)" style="font-size: 15px" value="" size="7" />
          <h1>Your education</h1>
          <h2>Your highest level of Education:</h2>
          <select onchange="compute(this.form)" name="highed">
            <option value="">Select One</option>
            <option value="1">No high school diploma or general Professional</option>
            <option value="2">High school general diploma +2 or 12th grade</option>
            <option value="3">Postsecondary diploma  2 years general  of full-time studies</option>
            <option value="4">Postsecondary technical diploma  1 year of full-time studies</option>
            <option value="4">Postsecondary technical diploma  2 years of full-time studies</option>
          </select>
          <h2>Your Area of Education:<small>(start typing..)</small></h2>
          <select class="flexselect" name="selectareaofstudy">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="6">3D Animation and Image Synthesis Techniques (DCS - 3 years) </option>
            <option value="6">LOADS OF OTHER VALUES HERE</option>
          </select>
          <br />
          <br />
          <INPUT class="ten" NAME="calc" VALUE="Calculate" TYPE="button" onClick="compute(this.form)">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <INPUT class="ten" NAME="calc" VALUE="Next" TYPE="button" onClick="show2()">
          <br />
        </div>
        <div id="part2" style="display:none">
          <h2>French Proficiency</h2>
          <p>Have you written: <strong>TCF Quebec/ TEFaQ/ TCF/ TEF level C2- DALF C2?</strong> </p>
          <div id="radio1" class="radio">
<!--These radio buttons have values of 1 and 2 but when calculated they always show up as zero, the default values.-->
            <input id="radio1-1" name="TCFC2" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" />
            <label for="radio1-1">Yes</label>
            <input id="radio1-2" name="TCFC2" type="radio" value="2"  />
            <label for="radio1-2">No</label>
          </div>
          <br />
          <br />
          <br />
          <INPUT class="ten" NAME="calc" VALUE="Calculate" TYPE="button" onClick="compute(this.form)">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td><INPUT class="ten" NAME="calc" VALUE="Back" TYPE="button" onClick="back2()"></td>
              <td><INPUT class="ten" NAME="calc" VALUE="Next" TYPE="button" onClick="show3()"></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div style="" id="totalmenu" class="port-menu-wrapper">
      <form id="total">
        <h3>Points For</h3>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><label>Age</label></td>
            <td><input class="sev" name="age" type="text" style="font-size: 15px" value="" size="7" readonly></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label style="font-size: 18px">Your Education</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label>Education 1</label></td>
            <td><input class="sev" name="ed" type="text" style="font-size: 15px" value="" size="7" readonly></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label>Area of Study</label></td>
            <td><input class="sev" name="aos" type="text" style="font-size: 15px" value="" size="7" readonly></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label style="font-size: 18px">French Proficiency</label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label>TCFC2</label></td>
            <td><input class="sev" name="tcfc2" type="text" style="font-size: 15px" value="" size="7" readonly></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label style="font-size:20px;"><strong>Total</strong></label></td>
            <td><input class="ten" name="total" type="text" style="font-size: 20px" value="" size="10" readonly></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Post your post here so anyone can help you out.

Comment: First thing I notice are some js errors: `c is not defined` and `show3 is not defined`. Also, how is it supposed to work? What exactly isn't working? We need more information.

Comment: c is defined in the if..else statements but show 3 is to be defined later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i don't think it's linked to jquery ui, but to the line

```
var tcfc2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('form').TCFC2.value, 10) || 0;
```

as you have 2 elements with radio buttons called TCFC2, an array is created with them. Moreover, the the value is always 1 for the first radio, and 2 for the second. You need to check the "checked" property, not the value to identify if people speak french.

```
var tcfc2 = document.getElementById('form').TCFC2[0].checked -0 ;
```

No parseInt, as "true" or "false" are returned, the "-0" is to force the int conversion.

Finally, I would rename the radios OR the input type text to something else than TCFC2. (and merge your css, get the scripts and styles out the html file and into their own files for maintenance stake, and name your vars to something more meaningful than a, b, and c...)

Comment: what if i want to award two points for yes and 1 point for no, and then add it to the total?

Comment: `var tcfc2 = document.getElementById('form').TCFC2[0].checked -0 +1;` or `var tcfc2 = document.getElementById('form').TCFC2[0].checked ? 2 : 1;`

Comment: Slightly less code, replace *getElementById* with *getElementsByName*: `document.getElementsByName('TCFC2')[0].checked`